# Construct variables based on other respondent's answer in a dyad in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Q_ID TeamID Answer Confidence Blur
1 A Yes 88 0 
1 A Maybe 99 0
1 B No 20 1
1 B Yes 22 1
1 C Definitely 32 2
1 C Yes 55 1
1 D No 33 5
1 D Maybe 33 9", header=T)
```

I want to group by TeamID and create a series of variables which reflect the other person's answers within a dyad.  The way I'm doing that currently is through manual construction like so:

```
> dat %>% mutate(partner_answer =  ave(Answer, TeamID, FUN = rev))
  Q_ID TeamID     Answer Confidence Blur partner_answer
1    1      A        Yes         88    0          Maybe
2    1      A      Maybe         99    0            Yes
3    1      B         No         20    1            Yes
4    1      B        Yes         22    1             No
5    1      C Definitely         32    2            Yes
6    1      C        Yes         55    1     Definitely
7    1      D         No         33    5          Maybe
8    1      D      Maybe         33    9             No
```

However, in my actual dataset I have some 100 variables that I want to create "partner" versions of, which I can match with the following regex:

```
index <- grepl('Answer|Confidence|Blur', names(dat))
```

Is there a convenient way within dplyr to automatically construct all the partner variables on the columns matched by index?  (e.g. `partner_confidence`, `partner_blur`)

Comment: With a self-join by team ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reverses the values in Answer, Confidence, and Blur for each dyad. Note that the reversal is performed on all columns that are NOT the grouping variables, so it should scale to any number of columns. Grouping by "Q_ID" may not be necessary, but your question was a little unclear on that point.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

dat.partner <- dat %>% 
  group_by(Q_ID, TeamID) %>% 
  mutate_all(rev) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-Q_ID, -TeamID) %>% 
  set_colnames(paste0('partner_', colnames(.)))

dat.final <- cbind(dat, dat.partner)

  Q_ID TeamID     Answer Confidence Blur partner_TeamID partner_Answer partner_Confidence partner_Blur
1    1      A        Yes         88    0              A          Maybe                 99            0
2    1      A      Maybe         99    0              A            Yes                 88            0
3    1      B         No         20    1              B            Yes                 22            1
4    1      B        Yes         22    1              B             No                 20            1
5    1      C Definitely         32    2              C            Yes                 55            1
6    1      C        Yes         55    1              C     Definitely                 32            2
7    1      D         No         33    5              D          Maybe                 33            9
8    1      D      Maybe         33    9              D             No                 33            5
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you!  What does `rev` do in this case?

Comment: `rev` reverses the order of items in a vector. Because I'm using it inside dplyr's `mutate_all` function, `mutate` is aware of the grouping by "TeamID", so in this case `rev` sees a bunch of 2-element vectors.